# ReplayKit Framework - Is it possible to only ask for permission once?

Tags: ios, replay

For Apple's new ReplayKit Framework in iOS 9 you have to get permission to access microphone and record screen.

It seems like on when I run my test application in xcode on on every start up it re-asks for permission when I already granted permissions in a previous session.

Is there a way to ask permission once (when a user starts up the app for the first time) and not have to ask again on every new session?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01QFu.jpg)

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: None... not sure what to do but file a bug report or feedback to apple.

Comment: It seems that this very alert is not even localised into any other language than English. I wonder how long lived ReplayKit will be - it seems that no one, the least Apple, cares about it.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this permission shows up every single time you start ReplayKit's screen recorder. No way to control this or make it remember.